# Kendo UI spreasheet - Adding tooltip or Comment to headers

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Is there any way to add toolip to header cell. We are using datasource to bind data to sheet.

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_, you might want to read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before doing so. Give a bit of context explaining what do you need, what have you tried so far, and why it isn't working as expected (i.e.: error messages, etc.). Also consider taking the time to format your question to be easily understood by readers.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I see to do this, is using the tooltip component:

```
  $("#target").kendoTooltip({
    autoHide: false
  });
```

But you have to find a way to insert an id to each cell in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Right now there is no in built support in kendo to add a tooltip for a cell. Is there anyway to get element associated with a cell. I am looking for a work around